# Parsing Hash - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, parsing, hash

I'm trying to parse a hash from LinkedIn, and running into an error

Here's the hash (converted from Mash) that I'm trying to parse:

```
#<LinkedIn::Mash first_name="John" headline="Recruiter" id="xxxxxxxx" industry="Telecommunications" last_name="Smith" location=#<LinkedIn::Mash country=#<LinkedIn::Mash code="us"> name="Greater Philadelphia Area"> positions=#<LinkedIn::Mash all=[#<LinkedIn::Mash company=#<LinkedIn::Mash id=2325416 industry="Staffing and Recruiting" name="Amazing Associates, Inc" size="1-10 employees" type="Privately Held"> id=9999999 is_current=true start_date=#<LinkedIn::Mash month=6 year=2010> summary="" title="Corporate Recruiter">] total=1> public_profile_url="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/greatguyjohn">
```

Here's the code I have:

```
<% if !connection["positions"].nil? %>
    <% connection["positions"].each do |positions| %>
        <% if !positions["all"].nil? %>
            <% positions["all"].each do |company| %>
                <%= company %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Here's the error:

```
can't convert String into Integer
Extracted source (around line #15):
12:         <% if !connection["positions"].nil? %>
13:             <% connection["positions"].each do |positions| %>
14:                 <% if !positions["all"].nil? %>
15:                     <% positions["all"].each do |company| %>
16:                         <%= company %>
17:                     <% end %>
```

The problem seems to be parsing the ["all"] hash from the ["positions"] hash.  I keep getting this error even though rest of hash parses fine.

Answer (score 0):

`connection["positions"]` will not return an array in your example. It returns a single `LinkedIn::Mash` hash object. You are erroneously calling `.each` on it.

Comment: Thanks, though what should I use instead?

Comment: Try `connection["positions"]["all"]`